# selecting radio button which matches the variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I currently have a bootstrap tab panel which consists of 3 tabs. Each tab has various number of checkboxes (I do not have control over this they are populated dynamically). What I am trying to achieve is to select the radio button with the id that matches my variable lets say 3. However, if the id does not match I always want to select the last check box.

This is what I have come up with so far.

```
var defaultSelection = 3;

if (defaultSelection) {
 var radioOptions = document.querySelectorAll('[name="firstSet"], [name="secondSet"], [name="thirdSet"]');

  for (var i = 0; i < radioOptions.length; i++) 
  {
     if (radioOptions[i].id === defaultSelection) 
     {
         document.querySelector("input[name=" + radioOptions[i].name + "][id=\'" + defaultSelection + "\']").checked = true;
     } else {
          //not entirly sure how to check the last item here in the particular tab
       }
     }
  }
```

Markup looks like:

```
<div class="d-flex flex-wrap">
<label class="radio-inline">
    <input type="radio" name="firstSet" id="1" value="1"> 1
</label>
<label class="radio-inline btn-sm">
    <input type="radio" name="firstSet" id="2" value="2"> 2
</label>
<label class="radio-inline btn-sm radio-active">
    <input type="radio" name="firstSet" id="3" value="3"> 3
</label>
<label class="radio-inline">
    <input type="radio" name="firstSet" id="4" value="4"> 4
</label>
<label class="radio-inline">
    <input type="radio" name="firstSet" id="5" value="5"> 5
</label>
</div>

<div class="d-flex flex-wrap">
<label class="radio-inline">
    <input type="radio" name="secondSet" id="25" value="25"> 25
</label>

<label class="radio-inline">
    <input type="radio" name="secondSet" id="27" value="27"> 27
</label>
</div>

<div class="d-flex flex-wrap">
<label class="radio-inline">
    <input type="radio" name="thirdSetSet" id="55" value="55"> 55
</label>
</div>
```

The above works to check the radio with the id which matches my variable but I'm not entirely sure how to select the last option in a particular tab if none are select or match my variable entry.

Any pointers would be helpful.

Comment: It would be useful to see a sample of the html structure so we could see the classes/tags for the selector. But my initial thought is you should use the last-child selector https://api.jquery.com/last-child-selector/

Comment: @TommyBs added markup sample as requested

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way you could go about this is by keeping track of whether the `default` radio button has been found and checked, and if that's not the case, then just check the last radio button.

Here's an example that implements this solution:

```js
var defaultSelection = 3;

if (defaultSelection) {
  var firstSet = document.querySelectorAll('[name="firstSet"]');
  var secondSet = document.querySelectorAll('[name="secondSet"]');
  var thirdSet = document.querySelectorAll('[name="thirdSet"]');

  var tabs = [].concat(firstSet, secondSet, thirdSet);

  tabs.forEach(function(tab) {
    // keep track of whether default has been checked and
    // grab the last radio button from the tab
    var isDefaultChecked = false;
    var lastRadioButton = tab[tab.length - 1];

    for (var i = 0; i < tab.length; i++) {
      var radio = tab[i];
      var isDefaultSelection = parseInt(radio.id, 10) === 3;

      // check the default radio button and
      // set `isDefaultChecked` to true
      if (isDefaultSelection) {
        radio.checked = true;
        isDefaultChecked = true;
      }
    }

    // if no radio button was checked,
    // check the last radio button
    if (!isDefaultChecked) {
      lastRadioButton.checked = true;
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<div class="d-flex flex-wrap">
 <label class="radio-inline">
  <input type="radio" name="firstSet" id="1" value="1" /> 1
 </label>
 <label class="radio-inline btn-sm">
  <input type="radio" name="firstSet" id="2" value="2" /> 2
 </label>
 <label class="radio-inline btn-sm radio-active">
  <input type="radio" name="firstSet" id="3" value="3" /> 3
 </label>
 <label class="radio-inline">
  <input type="radio" name="firstSet" id="4" value="4" /> 4
 </label>
 <label class="radio-inline">
  <input type="radio" name="firstSet" id="5" value="5" /> 5
 </label>
</div>

<div class="d-flex flex-wrap">
 <label class="radio-inline">
  <input type="radio" name="secondSet" id="25" value="25" /> 25
 </label>

 <label class="radio-inline">
  <input type="radio" name="secondSet" id="27" value="27" /> 27
 </label>
</div>

<div class="d-flex flex-wrap">
 <label class="radio-inline">
  <input type="radio" name="thirdSet" id="55" value="55" /> 55
 </label>
</div>
```